# VB6 - Creating a Connection String based on text input

Tags: vba, vb6, database-connection, connection-string

Ok I have a connection String - But I want to write an app where the user can enter their own values from a text box and that will be used in the connection

```
ConnectionObj.Open _
    "Provider = sqloledb;" & _
    "Data Source=" & Text1.Text; & _
    "Initial Catalog=" & text2.text; & _
    "User ID= text3.text ;" & _
    "Password= text5.text ;"
```

Here's what I've tried

But that didn't work - any help would be greate appreciated

Comment: Still none the wiser as to what actually happened apart it "didn't work". I guess it was the misplaced semicolons causing a compile time error?

Answer (score 0):

Since I figured it out I thought I'd post it : if someone would need this in the future :)

```
ConnectionObj.Open _
    ("Provider = sqloledb;" & _
    "Data Source=" & Text1.Text & _
    ";Initial Catalog=" & Text2.Text & _
    ";User ID=" & Text3.Text & _
    ";Password=" & Text4.Text & ";")
```

Just to make things absolutely clear the "&" is a concatenation operator "&_" denotes a continued (Long) line 
Best Task'